# Delete folder X older than x days in power shell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using PowerShell script to delete folders which are older than x days.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$path = "xxxx\path"

# Delete files older than the $limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files.
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`
```

But it doesn't work always, and I couldn't figure out what's wrong. is there any other way I can delete certain folders for example if there are more then 5 folders..? or is it best to delete which one is older..?

I do a backup via Powershell script which works great, but when I'm using this script to delete older backups some reason it doesn't work always.

is there any alternative way to do this.?

Lot's of love humans

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: It basically doesn't delete the folder or folders sometimes without any error.

Comment: What is the error which is thrown sometimes?

Comment: @Alex_P thanks, it's confusing but after changing the path for scripts they seem to be working. before path was like ( Users/admin/folder test/script.p1) I changed it to ( Users/admin/folder-test/script.p1)

Comment: Have you considered writing some test cases and scripts to create folders and set their created_dates to older dates, then debugging how to find them as you desire? You might get rid of the pipelines and store results in intermediate variables to also help debug.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `CreationTime` instead of the `LastWriteTime` property?

Comment: @Theo thanks just for curiosity why it would be good to use <LastWriteTime> property..?

Comment: Because files could have been created in the past, but updated at a much later time.

Answer (score 0):

> @Alex_P thanks, it's confusing but after changing the path for scripts they seem to be working. before path was like ( Users/admin/folder test/script.p1) I changed it to ( Users/admin/folder-test/script.p1)

after changing it solved the problem, still, don't know why it had happened.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Users/admin/folder test/script.p1" should have worked. There is a blank in the path. Therefore, "" are needed